# Clustering nodes to a corner instead of a circle in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

Can I use d3 force to cluster nodes in the corner of a screen? I don't want them to be in a clustered in a circle. Something 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xeok.png).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "transform" attribute to your container element.

Here's a working example forked from Mike Bostock's [Cluster Force Layout example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658):

https://jsfiddle.net/cmilneil/gpzavdqe/

The relevant bit of code is here. I'm adding a new `g` element and translating it into the corner of the containing `svg` element:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate(' + width/2 + ',' +  -height/2 + ')' );
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to lose 3/4 of all the nodes

Comment: yeah. I want to cluster ALL nodes to a corner.